# PDF indexing in MS-Dynamics 2016/365 search

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

We would like to enable attachments indexing in the MS-Dynamics search; by default search only searches through the records data (metadata) but not through the attached files. We would like to get search results, when a query is found in attached MS-Office or PDF document.

Can anyone advise if this can be done in the Dynamics itself, or does it required a 3rd party plugin, or maybe not possible at all?

We have MS-Dynamics 365 on-premise (it's called Dynamics 2016 Enterprise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in Dynamics 365. File attachments would need to be extracted, stored in an external repository and indexed.

Take a look at Lucene (open source) and ElasticSearch (based on Lucene).